# Error log de apache *** Error in `/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f0d48205898 ***

Tags: php, apache, moodle

Tengo instalado

- Apache/2.4.27 (Unix)
- Php 7.1.18
- mysql (5.6.43)
- moodle 3.6.2

En este mismo entorno tuve ya funcionando un moodle 3.5 y no ocurria esto, A las 12:25 el apache murio, ya no se podia acceder al sitio para que volviera a funcionar tuve que reiniciar apache.
En php.ini se usa `zend_extension=/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20160303/opcache.so`

y

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable = 1
opcache.memory_consumption = 128
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 10000
opcache.revalidate_freq = 60

; Requerido para Moodle
opcache.use_cwd = 1
opcache.validate_timestamps = 1
opcache.save_comments = 1
opcache.enable_file_override = 0
```

el log dice

```
7ffcc35f6000-7ffcc35f8000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
[Wed Jan 30 00:25:44.336640 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30582:tid 139695458514112] AH00052: child pid 16530 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed Jan 30 00:25:44.336700 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30582:tid 139695458514112] AH00052: child pid 16532 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed Jan 30 00:25:44.336710 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30582:tid 139695458514112] AH00052: child pid 16558 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jan 30 00:25:44.336719 2019] [core:notice] [pid 30582:tid 139695458514112] AH00052: child pid 16560 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
*** Error in `/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f0d48205898 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bfb)[0x7f0d614b6bfb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76fc6)[0x7f0d614bcfc6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7780e)[0x7f0d614bd80e]
/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp7.so(zend_hash_destroy+0x146)[0x7f0d5d5c6226]
/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp7.so(destroy_zend_class+0x1e1)[0x7f0d5d5a70e1]
/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp7.so(zend_hash_reverse_apply+0x159)[0x7f0d5d5c7829]
/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp7.so(+0x5714fa)[0x7f0d5d5a24fa]
/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp7.so(zend_deactivate+0xa4)[0x7f0d5d5b4c84]
/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp7.so(php_request_shutdown+0x424)[0x7f0d5d5440a4]
/usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp7.so(+0x63526f)[0x7f0d5d66626f]
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd(ap_run_handler+0x61)[0x561393b386d6]
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd(ap_invoke_handler+0x176)[0x561393b391ac]
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd(ap_process_async_request+0x744)[0x561393b579b1]
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd(+0x80fab)[0x561393b52fab]
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd(+0x811c5)[0x561393b531c5]
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd(ap_run_process_connection+0x61)[0x561393b47244]
```

Alguna idea para resolver, voy a probar la version 7.2 de php ya que la 7.3 aun no esta soportada

Comment: valida esa libreria con `ldconfig -p | grep libc.so.6` si no lo esta solo instala

Comment: Hola ya revise y sio se encuentra instalada libc.so.6 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.32) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Comment: jumm esta raro es algo de alguna libreria o hardware intenta eliminandolo del todo y dandole un force install

Comment: Hay [otros](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/110979/httpd-invalid-pointer-in-libphp7/) [casos](https://serverfault.com/questions/588748/glibc-detected-usr-sbin-httpd-free-invalid-pointer) por ahí...

Comment: A [alguien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722104/glibc-detected-usr-sbin-apache2-free-invalid-pointer) le funcionó revisar que OPcache no se cargara dos veces